# Generate mysql erd with connections

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, diagram, erd

I need to generate er diagram from dump of mysql database. I tryed a lot of tools like MySQL WorkBench and they generate only tables, but not connections between them. I need something like this http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/sql/database_schema.pdf (last page). Which software could make it? Thanks.

Comment: If your database does not contain meta data (like how which entry is a foreign key and to which table's primary key it is mapped), automatic tools cannot create connections between them and you will always end up with just tables. Did you try [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/)?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I'm a bit new in mysql. I made a few times SHOW CREATE TABLE command os diffirenet tables and they contain PRIMART KEY and FOREIGN KEY. I tryed DBVisualizer and it show only tables, but not connections in the references tab.

Comment: Oh, my fail. BD contain only PRIMARY KEY, not FOREIGN KEY. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[SchemaCrawler for MySQL](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a free tool that generates diagrams. SchemaCrawler can infer relationships between tables, based on commonly used naming conventions, and display these with dotted lines. Here is an [example diagram](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/images/diagram.png): [image: SchemaCrawler Diagram]

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)