# MySQL - Cannot create ERD in Server Instance Schemas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship, erd

I am brand new to MySQL and I am trying to understand how it all fits together. I have a very strong understanding of Microsoft Access, but this is a whole new world.

I create a schema (MySQL Model) and I had no problem creating an ERD. I then figured out how to Reverse Engineer it and add it to the local instance of my server which is Local Instance MySQL56.

But I cannot find the ERD on the local server. I then added more tables on the server, but I want to add the tables to the ERD so that I can relate the tables. But I cannot find any option to add or edit an ERD.

Am I missing something? How do I relate the tables without an ERD?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Without GUI you can run `ALTER TABLE` queries to define Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17737982/2055998) helps. I'm not familiar with the tool.

Comment: It's unclear if your question is about the tools or the concepts.  Do you know how to generate an ER model, and its diagram, with just pencil and paper?  Do you know how to design a relational (or SQL) model that mimics an ER model?  do you know how to do the project in SQL using the same methodology you would use in Access?  (BTW, I came at it the other way around.  I learned Oracle, among others, first.  Then I learned a little Access.  The hard part for me was learning to let the wizards do their thing.)

Comment: Hi Walter. Thanks for your response. I have been learning a lot about MySQL over the past few weeks. I have gotten more comfortable with it. I do know how to create the ERD's on paper, also with Microsoft Visio using crows feet notation. I also know how to create an ERD in Access and in MySQL. And I understand why I couldn't find the ERD in the local instance of the MySQL server.

Comment: I am still not comfortable with Make Table statements to create the tables and fields. I let the wizards do that, which is great. I understand the SQL that does that, but why worry about it when there are wizards that do it for you?

One caveat to my statement about not being comfortable with Make Table is that I have used it plenty of times in the back-end cod for Access. I find it useful to make temporary tables and then drop them when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PM 77-1, thanks for your responses. I am using Workbench for MySQL, which is a GUI.

I did discover the answer to my question by experimenting more with the tool.

While viewing the MySQL Server Instance, select the database that you are working on.
Select the Database Menu and Reverse Engineer...
For me, I just accepted all of the default options as I stepped through the wizard.

Then once I finish making all of the changes, reverse the process by doing a Forward Engineer.